# Jupyter's output is not consistent with local terminal in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm now using jupyter in vscode, when I type !nvcc -V, jupyter tells me no such a command, however, it works well in the seperated terminal, why this happens?
Thanks a lot!

I tried to uninstall the environment a lot of times but no helps.

Answer (score 0):

did you set up your python environment from Command Palette, from upper right corner

[image]

select Jupyter Kernel

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

Comment: Yes, and I select the jupyter kernel as the same as the python interpreter.

Comment: did you select the correct environment (env), that you have installed 'nvcc' package ?

Comment: I add the path of NVCC into the .bashrc, technically when I type 'nvcc' in whatever python environment I'm in.

Comment: maybe your VS code is using different shell (terminal), did you test opening a new terminal in the VS code and test 'nvcc' ?

Comment: Hey I found the problem, the `os.getenv('PATH')` is not the same as I use this command directly in terminal, but I did not figure out why

Comment: good, looks like your VS code terminal/shell was using different env than, your actual terminal/shell